# Programmatically split non-delimited strings and generate new columns

Tags: r, split, data.table

I have a 1 column data table containing non-delimited strings like so

```
d1 = data.table(x = c("2728661941-1945", "2657461921-1925", "2786161921-1925"))
d1
#>                  x
#> 1: 2728661941-1945
#> 2: 2657461921-1925
#> 3: 2786161921-1925
```

I have another data table of the form

```
dic = data.table(field = c("ID","group","year"),start=c(1,6,7), length=c(5,1,9))
dic
#>    field start length
#> 1:    ID     1      5
#> 2: group     6      1
#> 3:  year     7      9
```

I want to split the strings in the data table d1 using the information in dic, and end up with a new data frame of the form

```
d2 = data.table(ID = c("27286", "26574", "27861"), 
                group = c(6, 6, 6),
                year = c("1941-1945", "1921-1925", "1921-1925")
d2
#>       ID group      year
#> 1: 27286     6 1941-1945
#> 2: 26574     6 1921-1925
#> 3: 27861     6 1921-1925
```

I have tried

```
d2 = copy(d1)[,(dic$field) := transpose(
            lapply(x, stri_sub, from = dic$start, length = dic$length))]
```

But, the underneath data is in list form, not really in table form. I want to be able to refer to the created fields as columns.

I have to admit I am not entirely sure what I am doing, and I don't really have to use data table for this, but I can't think of another way to do it. The easiest dataset I have contains strings of 79 characters, and there are 25 fields that would be generated, so I would prefer not to have to pull each field individually.

I hope this makes sense. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) read.fwf** Try `read.fwf`.  No packages are used.

```
read.fwf(textConnection(d1$x), dic$length, col.names = dic$field)
```

giving:

```
     ID group      year
1 27286     6 1941-1945
2 26574     6 1921-1925
3 27861     6 1921-1925
```

**2) separate** This also works and gives the same answer:

```
library(tidyr)

d1 %>% 
   separate(x, sep = dic$start - 1, into = dic$field, remove = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

regex is useful here, particularly since you can programmatically define the patterns you want to search for and output

```
d1 %>% 
    mutate(x=gsub(paste0("(.{", dic$length, "})", collapse=""), paste0("\\", seq_along(dic$length), collapse=" "), x)) %>% 
    separate(x, into=dic$field, sep=" ")

     # ID group      year
# 1 27286     6 1941-1945
# 2 26574     6 1921-1925
# 3 27861     6 1921-1925
```

Explanation

```
# Pattern to search for
paste0("(.{", dic$length, "})", collapse="")
# "(.{5})(.{1})(.{9})"
      # (.{5}) - group that contains any 5 characters - will be group 1
      # (.{1}) - group that contains any 1 character - will be group 2
      # (.{9}) - group that contains any 9 characters - will be group 3

# Pattern to output
paste0("\\", seq_along(dic$length), collapse=" ")
# "\\1 \\2 \\3"
      # \\1 - output group 1
      # \\2 - output group 2
      # each group is separated by a space
```

Use `tidyr::separate` to split the resulting space-delimited string into distinct fields

Answer (score 2):

Not using the `dic` table, but this can be easily done with `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
extract(d1, x, c("ID", "group", "year"), "^(.{5})(.{1})(.{9})$")
```

**Result:**

```
      ID group      year
1: 27286     6 1941-1945
2: 26574     6 1921-1925
3: 27861     6 1921-1925
```

Comment: Thanks @useR, but this seems to require one to manually specify the field names and character lengths. It works great in this example, but I have many more fields and longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dic` table as reference:

```
library(dplyr)

breaks <- setNames(as.list(paste0("substr(x", ", ", dic$start, ", ", dic$start+dic$length-1, ")")), dic$field)

d1 %>% 
  mutate_(.dots = breaks)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(d1$x, function(X) sapply(1:NROW(dic),
   function(i) c(substring(X, dic$start[i], dic$start[i] + dic$length[i])))))), dic$field)
#      ID group      year
#1 272866    61 1941-1945
#2 265746    61 1921-1925
#3 278616    61 1921-1925
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `strcapture` function from base R to technically capture the strings. The we will input it in a dataframe that has been predefined.

```
 strcapture("(\\d{5})(\\d)(.*)",d1$x,data.frame(Id=numeric(),group=numeric(),year=character()))
     Id group      year
1 27286     6 1941-1945
2 26574     6 1921-1925
3 27861     6 1921-1925
```

Explanation: `(\\d{5})` captures the first 5 digits then `(\\d)` captures the next digits and `(.*)` captures everything else afterwards.

Comment: Please provide a proper detail and suggestion in the answer for better understanding.